# How to connect to oracle from php with tnsnames?

Tags: php, oracle, tnsnames

I am getting this error:
**Server Response='12154 ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

I am on Ubuntu 14.04
My environment variables are:

```
ORACLE_HOME = /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64​
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
TNS_ADMIN = /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin
```

tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora are within /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin

PS: I can connect through sqlplus with:

```
sqlplus64 user/pass@dbname
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $conn = oci_connect('user', 'pass', 'dbname');
?>
```

Comment: So -  please post the php code - I do not think you'll get help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It never worked on that way, what I did was to use Easy Connect string:
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pass', 'host/servicename'); however the first way should have worked because in another environments it works.

Answer (score 0):

tnsnames.ora file should look as follows

DBNAME=

    (DESCRIPTION=

       (ADDRESS=

          (PROTOCOL=TCP)

          (HOST=YOUR IP ADDRESS)

              (PORT=YOUR PORT NUMBER)

      )

      (CONNECT_DATA=

         (SERVICE_NAME=YOUR DBNAMEPROD)

      )

   )

conn.php file should look as follows

```
$USERNAME = "hr";                  // Login Username
$PASSWORD = "hr";             // Login Passowrd
$DATABASE = "DBNAME";   // Connect string to connect to your database found in tnsnames.ora
$conn = oci_connect($USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);

if(!$conn){
    echo "Your Connection Has an error";
}
else{
    echo "Your Connection is Successful"
}
```